# Difference between image warping and blur detection techinques

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Does blur detection algorithm detect image warping ? 
Bit confused as I don’t see much material differentiating the two. Are blur detection algorithm such as laplacian of variance able to detect image or video warping

Comment: No. A warped image is a nice, clean, not-blurred image and it is just a rotated (or transformed image) which is made digitally. A blurred image is kind of a noisy image which is made mostly by a random movement of the object or the camera.

Answer (score 0):

No, blur detection doesn’t detect warping.

Comment: Any inputs on how they are both different ?